# Why is my while loop triggering all the time no matter what I input?

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to do an assignment using a while loop in order to count how many tickets come through a gate and how log what color ticket it is. I thought I coded it correctly but then I got runtime errors and tried to single each mistake out and then 1 by 1 get it to work but I can't even get my while loop to not just trigger on anything the user puts in. Any help would be appreciated, I'm totally lost and I'm aware that this is very beginner.

```
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{


char answer;


cout << "start counting tickets? (y/n)" << endl;
cin >> answer;

while (answer = 'y')
{
    cout << "ok" << endl; 
    cin >> answer;
}



return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably meant `while (answer == 'y')`. Heed to your compiler warnings. If it didn't warn you, upgrade your compiler.

Comment: while (answer = 'y') means assign 'y' to the variable "answer". the value of "answer" is non-zero, this is why it is true. Because numberic value of 'y' in the ascii table isnt zero.

Comment: so what should I put instead?

Comment: Change the while line to "WhiZTim"'s answer.

Comment: Your code reads character by character. But if you intend the program to be interactive, the user will have to enter lines. That disconnect will cause you all kinds of problems as your second call to `cin >> answer` reads the newline at the end of the first y/n input.

Comment: Another example when using the highest compiler warning would solve the problem. Also, when you place the constant part as first it would even fail to compile when you don't use the most restrictive compiler warnings. `( 'y' == answer )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an assignment in your while loop condition. This is a common mistake made by beginners. You need to use the comparison operator instead.

Use

```
while (answer == 'y')
```

instead of

```
while (answer = 'y')
```

Using an assignment will always evaluate to "true" because assignments in C/C++ evaluate to the value assigned, and anything except 0 is considered "true". To avoid this mistake, some developers make a habit putting the constant on the left. For example:

```
while ('y' == answer)
```

That way, the compiler will generate an error if you mistakenly use the assignment operator. The same principle applies to "if" statements as well.

Comment: You might want to mention why this evaluates to true, and for a gold star consider whether this result is sensitive to the encoding used by the platform. And why some dudes put the constant on the left hand side.